# How to resolve "Quantifier hierarchy ended with a universal quantifier"?

Tags: boolean, formula, sat, cnf

I was trying to compile a QBF solver tool called CADET. CADET can only solve the format type of QDIMACS.

After the cloning of repository and installing the tool a simple command ie. `./cadet <filename>.qdimacs` is required to execute the file.  The photos of the error  and the QDIMACS file is given.

This is the .qdimacs file code

```
c This QDIMACS file encodes the formula     
c forall x1, x2 exists y. y <-> x1 & x2.
c x1 is represented by number 1
c x2 is represented by number 2
c y  is represented by number 3
p cnf 3 3                                   
a 1 2 0                                     
e 3 0                                       
1 -3 0                                      
2 -3 0                                      
-1 -2 3 0
```

This is warning I am getting during execution:

```
harish@harish-Lenovo-ideapad-510-15IKB:~/cadet$ ./cadet harish.qdimacs
CADET v2.5
Processing file "harish.qdimacs".
Warning: Quantifier hierarchy ended with a universal quantifier.
Warning: Removing last quantifier. Will obtain a propositional problem. This is a bit hacky, so beware.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a trailing space in the file due to which the tool could not execute properly.